# I need some help cleaning up my .htaccess file for redirects from expired pages

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've inherited an old website which has been through a few different domain names and file types. It used to have .aspx pages. Then it switched to .php (which it still is today). My .htaccess file is sort of a mess. I could use some help cleaning it up to accomplish the following:

Here's the history:

Old domain: stuff.olddomain.info

New domain: www.newdomain.com

The twist: www.newdomain.com used to have .aspx pages which are still indexed by Google

1. Redirect all old domain traffic to the new domain
2. Redirect all traffic to www
3. Redirect all .aspx traffic to the home page -> www.newdomain.com
4. The redirects from .aspx also have some variables at the end (www.newdomain.com/index.aspx?thing=123). I need to strip all of that extra stuff and just redirect to www.newdomain.com
5. Hide .php from all urls (www.newdomain.com/page.php shows as www.newdomain.com/page)

I have everything working except for the .aspx redirects. What am I missing?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# REDIRECT ASPX PAGES FROM PREVIOUS DOMAIN
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.aspx$ -f
RewriteRule www.newdomain.com [R=301,L]

### REDIRECT TO WWW FIRST
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# browser requests PHP
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# check to see if the request is for a PHP file:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

# Cache Control - 52 Weeks
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=3153600, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

I know that's probably a mess, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are checking whether `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.aspx$` actually exists as a physical file, which I assume it doesn't? (Plus, this is not a regular expression, masking the dot is wrong, and so is $, which would demand a literal dollar sign at the end of the existing file name here.) Remove that condition completely, and use a simple rule that checks whether the path ends with `.aspx`.

Comment: That _pattern_ part of the RewriteRule is not optional btw., right now `www.newdomain.com` is your _search pattern_, not what you are rewriting to. And even if it was, that would be a relative path, referring to the local file/folder named `www.newdomain.com`